# Print pdf into excel

Tags: java

i need to print PDF into excel sheet and take number from PDF as value in first column, in second column would be placed text from PDF. I have code that can read PDF but i struggle with saving it into excel (only .txt works for me). thank you.

```java
public class saveData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("C:/Users/jurkeda1/Desktop/TestERV/layout1_3333445.pdf");

        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = null;
            try {
                stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                String text = stripper.getText(document);

                // Creating a File object that represents the disk file.
                PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("C:/Users/jurkeda1/Desktop/TestERV/OUT.txt"));
                // Store current System.out before assigning a new value
                PrintStream console = System.out;
                // Assign o to output stream
                System.setOut(o);
                System.out.println(text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You need to use an external library in order to create Excel files, like *.xlsx*. Have a look at [apache-poi](https://poi.apache.org/) and check out classes like `XSSFWorkbook`, for example.

Comment: File fileX = new File("C:/Users/jurkeda1/Desktop/TestERV/template_VMV.xlsx");
FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(fileX);XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fip); but still text isnt saved in excel

Comment: You need a `FileInputStream` if you want to **read** an existing `XSSFWorkbook`, try to use a `FileOutputStream`...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can write a workbook like this:

```
// create a new workbook instance
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

// ...
// write data into the workbook and format the data
// data may be written by adding and configuring instances of XSSFSheet, XSSFRow and XSSFCell
// ...

// then write the workbook into a file (until here, it is in the RAM)
try {
    // create a new FileOutputStream with the path to the file (don't forget the extension)
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Y:\\our\\path\\to\\the\\file.xlsx");
    // then write the workbook using that stream
    workbook.write(fos);
    // force the stream to write everything out of the buffers
    fos.flush();
    // and close it afterwards
    fos.close();
    // same for the workbook resource
    workbook.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // inform about the special exception, maybe
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // inform about the special exception, maybe
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need to find out yourself how to add a new sheet and how to add new rows and cells to a sheet. This is just an example of how to write the instance of `XSSFWorkbook` to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add `Apache POI` dependencies in your **pom.xml** file :

```
</dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

An example of  **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache-extras.beanshell</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>2.0b6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Create a class to manage the PDF data *[Optional]*:

```
public class CustomPDFValue 
{
    private String number;
    private String PDFText;

    public CustomPDFValue(String number, String PDFText) 
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.PDFText = PDFText;
    }

    public String getNumber() 
    {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) 
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getPDFText() 
    {
        return PDFText;
    }

    public void setPDFText(String PDFText) 
    {
        this.PDFText = PDFText;
    }
}
```

Now you need to create a **Workbook** and a **Sheet**:

```
private void exportAsExcel()
{
   try
   {
      // Create dump data for this example
      List<CustomPDFValue> customPdfValueList = new ArrayList<>();
      customPdfValueList.add(new CustomPDFValue("1", "text 1"));
      customPdfValueList.add(new CustomPDFValue("2", "text 2"));
      customPdfValueList.add(new CustomPDFValue("3", "text 3"));
      customPdfValueList.add(new CustomPDFValue("4", "text 4"));
      customPdfValueList.add(new CustomPDFValue("5", "text 5"));
      customPdfValueList.add(new CustomPDFValue("6", "text 6"));
      Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
      Sheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sample");
      int rowIndex = 0;
      int columnIdexNumber = 0;
      int columnIdexPDFText = 1;
      // Create a row at index 0
      Row row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowIndex);
      // Add a title to the fist cell in the 'row'
      row.createCell(columnIdexNumber).setCellValue("Numbers");
      // Add a title to the second cell in the 'row'
      row.createCell(columnIdexPDFText).setCellValue("PDF text");
      rowIndex++;
      // Now fill the rows with the values taken from the PDF
      for(CustomPDFValue customPDFValue: customPdfValueList)
      {
         // Create a new row and add a number and a text
         row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowIndex);
         row.createCell(columnIdexNumber).setCellValue(customPDFValue.getNumber());
         row.createCell(columnIdexPDFText).setCellValue(customPDFValue.getPDFText());
         rowIndex++;
      }
      // Optional: you can autosize the columns
      for(int i = 0; i < customPdfValueList.size(); i++)
      {
        spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
      }
      String pathFile = "sample.xls";
      // Save your excel
      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(pathFile);
      workbook.write(fileOut);
      fileOut.close();
      workbook.close();
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Your output should be like this: [image: The excel file generated.]